# Pentaho - Carte Dowload a file

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-spoon, pentaho-data-integration

I'm trying to use pentaho service carte to execute a ETL and return the file generated. How I can do this? Someone knows  that it is possible or there is a other service to can do this?

Thanks!!!